# Does Circle CI 2.0 invalidate cache key when changing docker images

Tags: circleci, circleci-2.0

I want my cache to become invalid when I change container build images. Does that happen automatically or do I need to marry the cache key to the build container image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From support ticket:

If you're using a new container build image, the old cache shouldn't be used (since it's irrelevant), and a new one will be created. Of course, rotating cache keys will also ensure a fresh cache.

Comment: Can you add a link?

Comment: No, the support ticket is in my email

Comment: Ok.  Is this behaviour documented anywhere?  It's not what I would expect, and it seems unintuitive that a change to the Docker image should invalidate the build cache (which is generally caching things unrelated to the image itself).

Comment: No, it's not documented anywhere. That's why I posted a question and answer.